# How to force a package to be installed?

Tags: php, composer-php, laravel-5, cartalyst-sentry, packagist

I'm trying to install the following package through `composer`:

https://packagist.org/packages/cartalyst/sentry#dev-feature/laravel-5

When I do:

```
composer require cartalyst/sentry dev-feature/laravel-5
```

I always receive this error:

```
[InvalidArgumentException]
Could not find package dev-feature/laravel-5 at any version for your minimum-stability (stable). Check the package spelling or your minimum-stability
```

If I change `minimum-stability` to `dev` it will still complain.

However, if I install `dev-master` and manually merge the files from `dev-feature/laravel-5` into `dev-master`, it works fine.

Hence why I'm asking how to force this package to be installed via `composer`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To force the installation of this package, I added the following to the `require` element of `composer.json`:

```
"cartalyst/sentry":"dev-feature/laravel-5 as 2.1.4"
```

Below is the link from where I found this suggestion:

http://vvv.tobiassjosten.net/php/have-composer-use-development-branches/

It will not work from the command line, must be through `composer.json`. That I don't know why.

**Update:**

I believe I was wrong in my last statement above, actually something like the following will work from the command line:

```
composer require "codeception/codeception":"2.1.0-rc1 as 2.0.9"
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to use this

```
composer require "cartalyst/sentry": "2.0.*@dev"
```

I believe sentry is not fully compatible with Laravel 5 yet