# Install Package From Packagist Failed

Tags: php, composer-php, packagist

I never use `composer` to install any package before. so this is my first time and I got this error message :

```
# composer require "neilgarb/bitx"


[InvalidArgumentException]                                                                                                                     
Could not find package neilgarb/bitx at any version for your minimum-stability (stable). Check the package spelling or your minimum-stability
```

and it doesn't produce anything at the end. how to solve this installation error? thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force a package to be installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28442158/how-to-force-a-package-to-be-installed)

Comment: That package only has `dev-master` until a tag is made you will need to use `"minimum-stability": "dev"` in your composer file. Open an issue about it, the lib looks abandoned though.